# React - Can't display Image passed through react component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here.

How can i display the image from the react component **CheckoutProduct** props in within the image html tag.

[Picture showing failed image display of the Product item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXkut.jpg)

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import './CheckoutProduct.css'
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";


function CheckoutProduct({id, image, title, price, rating}) {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();  

  return (
    <div className='checkoutProduct'>
        <image className='checkoutProduct__image' src={image}/>

         
          <div className='checkoutProduct__info'>
              <p className="checkoutProduct__title">{title}</p>
                <p className="checkoutProduct__price">
                    <small>$</small>
                    <strong>{price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="checkoutProduct__rating">
                    {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) => (<p></p>))}
                </div>
              <button>Remove from Basket</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CheckoutProduct
```

The rest of the code is here https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Amazon-Clone-With-React/blob/master/src/CheckoutProduct.js

Comment: Shouldnt it be <img> instead of <image>

Comment: Thanks kevin, it worked. Wasn't seeing it all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `<image>` tag to `<img/>`.

`<image/>` wont work as it's not the correct one.

```
<img className='checkoutProduct__image' src={image}/>
```